# I need help creating a ringing sound, as heard in this link

Tags: film, dialogue

As the title suggests, I need help creating a particular sound effect for a film I am working on.  An example of the effect I am looking for is at 1:40 in the link below;

Around 1:40 the patient (I forget the actors name) goes into a trance like state and you hear a ringing sound effect coupled with the doctors voice becoming echo-like.

I know the echo effect can be created by putting reverb on the dialogue track and slowly automating the dry/wet channel upwards, but I have no clue how to get a good 'ringing' sound to go along with it.

Does anyone have any experience on creating an effect like this?  Please share!

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pure sinus of about 1400 Hz (1.4 Khz), most DAW's will have a function to generate a few seconds of that. In Adobe Audition you would go to the menu `Generate` -> `Tones`.

[image: Generate a 1400Hz tone]

Then add some "dirt" to it using something like [Izotope Vinyl](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/vinyl/) (it's a free plugin).

[image: Add some record player dust]

I guess that would be the basics of what you want. Maybe instead of adding dirt, subtracting some "holes" is more like it, but the 1400Hz sine is surely the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Scan through [this search query](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=ear%20ring) for some possible answers. This question has been discussed in the old SSD forum many times over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scraped metal sounds, with a lot of eq, pitch and maybe some ring modulation.

Comment: While this is a decent start of an answer, it really doesn't give much in the way of detail.  If you could expand on what kind of adjustments you'd make to EQ and how you would modulate, it would help the answer be far more helpful.